# Compiling and minifying extra CSS files and JS with Vite

Tags: reactjs, laravel, sass, vite

I am building a laravel app with reactJs and Vite compiler.
I am trying to tell the vite compiler to also compile extra SCSS and JS files and put them into the build folder.
these files are not imported by my reactJs app, so naturally the compiler doesn't see them and i only need them for another process other than the frontEnd.

i checked the [copyPublicDir](https://vitejs.dev/config/build-options.html#build-copypublicdir) but it doesn't seem to work for the SCSS file compilation. Is there a way to do it ? i used to this with webpack but i am new to the Vite compiler

Comment: Just import them into bootsrap.js and vite compile them. Or downgrade to laravel mix - mix can just copy files. Vite cannot.